# In Rails can i add two instace variables to a loop working with the Simple Calender gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calendar

I am trying to create a simple time table for when i log in and out of work. i am using the **simple_calendar gem** i have a calender in my home index and two controllers created with scaffold. rails g scaffold clockin name start_time:date and
rails g scaffold clockout name start_time:date.

My home/index file looks like this :

```
<%= month_calendar events: @clock_ins do |date, clock_ins| %>
<%= date %>
<% clock_ins.each do |clock_in| %>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
    <%= clock_in.name %>
    <%= clock_in.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %P") %>
  </button>
   
  </div>
<% end %>
```

<% end %>

[image]

I cant seem to figure out how to get the clockout data to appear on the calender as well as the clock in. is it possible to iterate through two controllers in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With how you have things now, you could combine the `@clock_ins` and `@clock_outs` into one array and iterate over the two at the same time. Make sure to add the `@clock_outs` instance variable in your controller action

```
<%= month_calendar events: [*@clock_ins, *@clock_outs] do |date, events| %>
  <%= date %>
  <% events.each do |event| %>
    <div>
      <% if event.is_a?(ClockIn) %>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
          <%= event.name %>
          <%= event.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %P") %>
        </button>
      <% elsif event.is_a?(ClockOut) %>
        <button type="button" class="btn">
          <%= event.name %>
          <%= event.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %P") %>
        </button>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You could also try having *one* model for both clock-ins and clock-outs. Maybe call it `CalendarEvent` with a column that states if it's `clock_in` or `clock_out` (make sure not to name that column `type`, that will freak out ActiveRecord).

Comment: Brilliant exactly what i was looking for thank you very much